# ORA-01017: invalid username/password when connecting to 9i oracle database using the ODP.NET, Managed Driver

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net, oracle9i

I'm trying to connect to 9i oracle database using the ODP.NET, Managed Driver. Every time I see ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied.

Wnen I'm trying to connect to 10g or higher oracle database - all is well.

Also, when I'm trying to connect to 9i oracle database using .Net Framework for Oracle or .Net Framework for OLE DB (MSDAORA) - all is well.

What is the problem?

Comment: Maybe it is not very smart to connect with a brand new Driver to a stone-aged Database.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, maybe you know the correct way?

Comment: In Oracle 9i the password was not case-sensitive. Try to set password all upper-case, perhaps it helps - although it is a catch at a straw.

Comment: I just got another idea, set Oracle parameter [SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams211.htm) to false, maybe it helps.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, I tried it all. Unsuccessfully. Maybe you're right about "a stone-aged Database", but I can't find official documents that may confirm this.

Comment: Microsoft provides are also deprecated for long time. Try drivers from Oracle (i.e. `System.Data.OleDb` with `Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle` or `Oracle.DataAccess.Client`)

Comment: In general (not always) Oracle drivers and client applications support database versions back to the terminal release from two major versions ago. So ODP.NET 12.1 supports back to 10.2. For confirmation of this, always check the documentation or worldwide support website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be not possible, have a look at [ODAC 12c Release 2 (12.1.0.1.2) Installation Instructions, Setup, and Notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/install121012-2088160.html)

> **System Requirements**
>
> - Access to an Oracle Database Server (**Oracle 10g Release 2 or
>     later**)

Comment: This is the correct answer. In general (not always) Oracle drivers and client applications support database versions   back to the terminal release from two major versions ago. So ODP.NET 12.1 supports back to 10.2. For confirmation of this, always check the documentation or worldwide support website.